# Strings in C - print is the same strcmp says they are not

Tags: c, strtok, strcmp

Hi guys I am having a problem with my server client project. I run my proxy server with the command `./server www.google.com`  so i have `argv[1]=www.google.com`. After this I run my client and I send to the server the value `GET www.google.com`. Now from server side I use `strtok_r(buffer," ",&string1)` so I have `buffer=GET` and `string1=www.google.com` (I'm sure for these valuse cause I print them). The problem is when I use

```
if((strcmp(string1,argv[1]) == 0))
        {       
            printf(" SAME VALUES \n");
        }
```

I don't get the printf so these 2 variables don't have the same value. Any ideas ?

Comment: Inspect the raw data (with a hex print, debugger, etc). Possibly there is some leading/trailing whitespace or newline remaining.

Comment: Most likely string1 has white space at the end. Consider trimming it, or writing a custom compare function which also stops at newline.

Comment: print values of string1 and argv[1] by bytes and check for differences

Comment: Show some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Add `printf("string1 = [[%s]], arg 1 = [[%s]]\n", string1, argv[1]);` before the comparison.  The square brackets serve to delimit the strings.  If the close square brackets are near the start of the line, suspect CR `'\r'` characters in the string. If they're on the next line, assume LF `'\n'` characters in the string.

Comment: Not sure the value of string1 is reliable. Believe the docs/specs on strtok_r indicate that the first call with a given first parameter should also cause the third parameter (*saveptr) to be ignored. So you may be *seeing* that value when you print string1, but it may be unreliable content that is the hidden cause of the problem.

Comment: Hyde was right!. It was a whitespace problem.I just used a function that deletes the whitespaces .PROBLEM SOLVED :)

Answer (score 1):

In `strtok_r(buffer," ",&string1)`, `string1` isn't the pointer to the token found. You appear to be comparing `string1` but the function return value is the token pointer. So the code should be

```
char * tok = strtok_r(buffer," ",&string1);
if ((strcmp (tok,argv[1]) == 0))
    {       
        printf(" SAME VALUES \n");
    }
```

Comment: This is correct. May I suggest that you expand your answer a bit. Perhaps, add something like this: `char* p;` `char* tok;` `tok = strtok_r(buffer, " ", &p);`...

Comment: @Brad S. thanks, but OP seems to have solved his question somehow. I was guessing, as the only code properly posted was the bit that worked.